# xlwings: "No name 'Book' in module 'xlwings'"

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

so I'm taking my first steps with python and since I'm mainly working with Excel, the package xlwings seems very interesting to me.

However, I can't make it to run even the tests, since I seem to have some kind of dependency missing.

Here's the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import xlwings as xw

wb = xw.Book()
```

and I get a `No name 'Book' in module 'xlwings'` error.

I'm running a MacOS Catalina 10.15.6 and Python version 3.9.0

This is the output of the comand `pip show xlwings`:

```
Name: xlwings
Version: 0.20.8
Summary: Make Excel fly: Interact with Excel from Python and vice versa.
Home-page: https://www.xlwings.org
Author: Zoomer Analytics LLC
Author-email: felix.zumstein@zoomeranalytics.com
License: BSD 3-clause
Location: /Users/david/.pyenv/versions/3.9.0/lib/python3.9/site-packages
Requires: psutil, appscript
Required-by:
```

I have seen the same question asked here but the solution was the capitalization of the word "Book", which is not the issue in this case as I've tested both options. I also tried using workbook()/Workbook().

What am I doing wrong? Am I missing any packages?

Comment: Is it possible that you have named your test script `xlwings.py` ? If so, rename it and you should be good.

Comment: try with  xw.book()

.Book() with mayus is only for api